# npm postinstall script works but does finish with failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I tried, but didn't find a solution for my problem. I have a simple package.json with a postinstall script. This script starts running an does its work. Nevertheless the npm install process stops with a failure message.

Basically the postinstall script requires a connection to the database and refers to a function. The data in the obj is written into the database. Do I need to end the script in some way. As mentioned, the script works, the data is in the database.

I am installing the npm via
"npm pack"
"npm install test-file-1.0.0.tgz"

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-file",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "do something",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "basic/data.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test"
  ],
  "author": "any",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

My data.js file:

```
let db = require('../../../db');

let obj = {
    name: 'the name',
    id: 'some id',
    description: 'description'
};

db.saveDataToDatabase(obj);
```

The failure messages:

```
(##################) ⠦ reify:test-file: sill audit bulk request {
npm ERR! path /home/am/test-folder/node_modules/test-file
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGINT
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./basic/data.js
npm ERR! {
npm ERR!   name: 'the name',
npm ERR!   id: 'some id',
npm ERR!   description: 'description'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/am/.npm/_logs/2022-08-23T12_42_07_883Z-debug-0.log
```

The failure log:

```
1061 info run test-file@1.0.0 postinstall { code: null, signal: 'SIGINT' }
1062 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 9ms
1063 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
1064 timing command:install Completed in 1080825ms
1065 verbose stack Error: command failed
1065 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:63:27)
1065 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
1065 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
1065 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
1066 verbose pkgid test-file@1.0.0
1067 verbose cwd /home/am/test-folder
1068 verbose Linux 5.10.17-v7l+
1069 verbose node v16.16.0
1070 verbose npm  v8.11.0
1071 error path /home/am/test-folder/node_modules/test-file
1072 error command failed
1073 error signal SIGINT
1074 error command sh -c node ./basic/data.js
1075 verbose exit 1
1076 timing npm Completed in 1081170ms
1077 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1661255951483
1078 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1661255968543
1079 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1661255968545
1080 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1661255968545
1081 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1661255968547
1082 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/test-file 1661255968548
1083 verbose code 1
1084 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
1084 error     /home/am/.npm/_logs/2022-08-23T11_59_11_155Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself. The npm install process stops with a failure message, because the script 'postinstall' is still active. It can be closed with `process.exit();`

```
saveData(obj);

async function saveData(data){
    await db.saveDataToDatabase(data);
    process.exit();
}
```